# VLOOKUP that looks in descending order

Tags: excel

I am looking to do a VLOOKUP that moves down a list and then returns errors when done. e.g.

```
Apple     6
Apple     7
Apple     9
Apple     345
Apple     3546
Curry     2
```

If this is my excel sheet, I'd like to return this:

```
Apple     6         7        9       345       3456         #N/A
```

It's perfectly fine for this to be 6 functions.

I've tried this function:

```
=INDEX(Pivot1!$C:$C,MATCH(Report!$D9,Pivot1!$B:$B,1)+4)
```

Where the +4 changes for each column. So the second value would be +2. However, this just keeps going down the list and returns the curry value instead of the apple.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following screenshot.

The formula has been entered into cell G2 and copied across and down.

```
=IF(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($F2,$A:$A,0)+COLUMN(A1)-1)=$F2,INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($F2,$A:$A,0)+COLUMN(A1)-1),NA())
```

The formula first does a lookup on the name in column A. If that name matches the name in F2, then a lookup on the Value column will be performed, otherwise a #N/A! error will be returned.

[image]

Of course, you can use a `""` instead of `NA()` to make the cell appear blank instead of showing the error.

Edit: if your data goes down more rows than the COLUMN() function can handle, you need a different approach. Insert a helper column into the data that creates a unique lookup key, for e.g.

```
=A2&COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)
```

Then you can use a simple Index/Match to perform the lookup.

```
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($E2&COLUMN(A1),$C:$C,0))
```

[image]

Comment: How do you adjust the A1 in the column function if your column is tens of thousands of rows?

Comment: In that case you will need a helper column in your data to facilitate a different approach.  I edited my anser to explain how